# Loop a number write in console

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm doing an exercise to train myself and I'm currently blocked with a variable in my loop.

main.py

```py
from interface import *
from function import *

player_number(choose_pseudo)
```

interface.py

```py
list_players = []


def player_number(callback):
    players = int(input("Nombre de joueurs ? [1 à 4]\n"))
    callback(players)


def choose_pseudo(p):
    for i in range(p):
        player = input("Joueur " + i + " choisissez un pseudo ?\n").lower()
        list_players.append(player)
```

I want to loop in the second function the number of player who is enter with console (so a string).

EDIT: error

```
Nombre de joueurs ? [1 à 4]
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antoine/Projet/Python AP1/MarioParty/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    player_number(choose_pseudo)
  File "/home/antoine/Projet/Python AP1/MarioParty/function.py", line 6, in player_number
    callback(players)
  File "/home/antoine/Projet/Python AP1/MarioParty/function.py", line 11, in choose_pseudo
    player = input("Joueur " + i + " choisissez un pseudo ?\n").lower()
TypeError: must be str, not int

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is an int, so you need to convert it to string inside your `input` call:

```
player = input("Joueur " + str(i) + " choisissez un pseudo ?\n").lower()
```

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't thinking about it :o